# Printf %d in string formating digits

Tags: bash, awk, printf

I want to transform this

```
bottle-1.wt
...
bottle-88.wt 
...
```

Into

```
bottle-001.wt
...
bottle-088.wt 
...
```

I tried the following:

```
myBottle=bottle-1.wt
printf "bottle-%03d.wt" $myBottle
```

However `$myBottle` is a string and `%03d` don’t work.

Comment: Why is `$myBottle` a string instead of a number?

Comment: @Barmar it’s a file name

Comment: You mean it's the original `bottle-1.wt` filename? Get the number out of it and use that.

Comment: @Barmar With tr or sed for instance ?

Comment: ...or [bash's native string-manipulation primitives](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100), which are far more efficient (for short invocations on small amounts of data). See also [the bash-hackers' wiki page on parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe).

Comment: Consider `printf 'bottle-%03d.wt' "${myBottle//[^[:digit:]]/}"` as another approach (just removing *all* non-digit characters during the expansion process).

Comment: BTW, one caveat -- if your value is *already* padded with leading zeroes, you can get an `Invalid number` error on account of the shell trying to parse it as octal.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Or `${myBottle//[^0-9]}`, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58098160/1765658). Note that `${myBottle//[^[:digit:]]/}` don't work under [tag:dash] too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the prefix and suffix from the filename to get the number.

```
myBottle=bottle-1.wt
temp=${myBottle#bottle-} #remove bottle- prefix
temp=${temp%.wt} # remove .wt suffix
shopt -s extglob # needed for next command
temp=${temp##+(0)} # remove leading zeroes
printf "bottle-%03d.wt" "$temp"
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you are ok with `awk`, you could try following.

```
myBottle="bottle-1.wt"
echo "$myBottle" |  awk '
  match($0,/-[0-9]+\./){
    printf("%s-%03d.%s\n",substr($0,1,RSTART-1),substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1),substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH))
}'
bottle-001.wt
```

Answer (score 1):

perl equivalent:

```
$ printf "bottle-%d.wt\n" {6..15}
bottle-6.wt
bottle-7.wt
bottle-8.wt
bottle-9.wt
bottle-10.wt
bottle-11.wt
bottle-12.wt
bottle-13.wt
bottle-14.wt
bottle-15.wt
$ printf "bottle-%d.wt\n" {6..15} | perl -nE '/(.*?)([0-9]+)(.*)/;printf "%s%03d%s\n", $1,$2,$3'
bottle-006.wt
bottle-007.wt
bottle-008.wt
bottle-009.wt
bottle-010.wt
bottle-011.wt
bottle-012.wt
bottle-013.wt
bottle-014.wt
bottle-015.wt
```

Explanation of the perl part:

```
-n: Run the command per line of the input
-E: Run expression/script from command-line argument.

/(.*?)([0-9]+)(.*)/ : Match the 3 parts of the string as "bottle-", "8", ".wt"
printf "%s%03d%s\n", $1,$2,$3: printf the 3 components as required.
```

For visual explanation and experimenting: https://regex101.com/r/qiFvv1/2